# How to disable Dropdown in infopath IE doesn't but It works in FF

Tags: sharepoint-designer, infopath, jquery, internet-explorer, cross-browser

I have a element of type dropdown I would like to disable in an InfoPath form based on a user's group membership.
When I use the below code it works in FF but not in IE 10.

```
$("#ctl00_m_g_480f90e8_e144_49f7_818e_674ef1e6b705_FormControl0_V1_I1_D3").prop("disabled",true);
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why don't you use the regular InfoPath way to disable the control? Why would you want to use jQuery in the first place?

Comment: sorry didn't elaborate. Can InfoPath disable based on username or groups?
Cheers

Comment: Yes it can. Why don't you post the real question.

Comment: Thanks teylyn.
I came across this : http://info.akgroup.com/blog-0/bid/69277/InfoPath-Restrict-visibility-to-users-in-a-SharePoint-Group

Comment: Can you please update your question to state the real issue. It looks like you want to hide parts of the form based on a user's group membership. So ask that.

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery(selector).attr("disabled","disabled") and jQuery(selector).removeAttr("disabled"), then it will work in IE as well.